# Launch Python script from Cron in foreground

Tags: python, cron

I have developed a Python script that I would like to run at every boot of the Pi.  The script in question is one that I do not want to run in the background.  It will be controlling the display of webpages in a kiosk-like slideshow.

So far I have included the below in the `crontab` file edited via `sudo`:

`@reboot \usr\bin\python3 \home\pi\Desktop\photo_frames\get_random_row.py > /logs/cronlog`

Not only does this not run in the foreground, the logs indicate a Selenium error despite my ability to explicitly/manually run the Python script from terminal without issue.

Any help/explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

To run in foreground you'd need to add `DISPLAY=:0`:

```
@reboot DISPLAY=:0 \usr\bin\python3 \home\pi\Desktop\photo_frames\get_random_row.py > /logs/cronlog
```

Or open it explicitly with `xterm`:

```
@reboot DISPLAY=:0 xterm -e \usr\bin\python3 \home\pi\Desktop\photo_frames\get_random_row.py /logs/cronlog
```

Generally if it's Python, you could use logging library instead of stdout and redirection.